# Android - how to kill all activities when HOME is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, garbage-collection, manifest

I have an application containing multiple activities.

At the moment the whole application contains about 8 activities. First I show a splash screen for a few seconds where all the preferences are loaded and set up (from sharedPreferences) - these are saved in a "Setting" class I made for this - this class basicly just have a bunch of static variables, so all activities in the app can read these and modify them as they need to.

**EDIT**: More data is getting stored in this class as the app runs, some of this is from a webservice - the data is parsed into obejcts and references to these obejcts are saved in the Settings class too (or a list of the objects).

My problem is then, that when users press the HOME key, the current activity is put in the background. If the activity is in the background for a long time (a lot of users "close" apps by pressing home instead of back), and then reopened it shows the activity that was running before HOME was pressed.

As an example - lets say the user starts the app, sees the Splash screen for a few seconds. The splash screen then starts a new activity and calls finish on itself.

This means that now the Activity stack is just the MainActivity (main menu). In the MainActivity I supply all the buttons with listeners in the onCreate method, and most buttons require some info from the Settings class mentioned above.

When I then press HOME and reopens the app a few hours later, none of the buttons works anymore - seems the graphic is reacting etc, but something still goes wrong. One of the buttons that should work even with all settings wiped will just open a dialog with some text in it.

The listener:

```
Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.id_b1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Dialog dialog = createDialog(MainActivity.this, DIALOG_CONST1);
    dialog.show();
  }
});
```

I have some constantst for dialog types, as I'm using some custom designs for the dialogs I have created a class to created the dialogs for me.

From the activity containing the button (simplified a bit):

```
public static Dialog createDialog(final Context c, int dialogId) {
  Dialog dialog = null;
  CustomDialog.Builder customBuilder;
  switch (dialogId) {
    ...
    case d1:
      customBuilder = new CustomDialog.Builder(c, DIALOG_CONST1);

      //Sets up the parapters to create the dialog afterwards
      customBuilder.setTitle("Header").setMessage("Content")
      .setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      });
      dialog = customBuilder.create(); //Creates the dialog from the above settings
      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
      break;
    ...
  }
  ... //Set the width of the dialog
  return dialog;
}
```

The CustomDialog class extends the Dialog class and then depending on the const it
s supplied with it inflates one of several dialog layouts and adds content etc. Works great normally, but after the app have been paused by HOME for a while, and things go wrong no dialog is shown when I press the button. I do se a flash of a loading dialog on the other buttons, but nothing happens afterwards - no dialog is shown. Strange thing is that if I press on the button again in the middle of the screen, I can't press it (grahics dont react), but when pressing once in the side of the screen and then in the middle the graphics do react, the dialogs does get cancelled when pressing outside, so I'm wondering if there is some very slim "transparent" dialog in the middle or something - I just have no clue why this would happen.

**EDIT**: Actually looking through the variables I save in Settings class I see that I do save the width and height in pixels of the screen. Width used to set the width of the custom dialogs to a certain % of the screen width. IF the Settings gets wiped, that might explain why I don't see any dialogs as width is set to 0... I really can't seem to figure what is happening if it's not all my variables in the Settings class that gets wiped - everything really do point to that.

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(Settings._widthpx - (Settings._widthpx/5), dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height); //Width = 80%
```

Actually I have to admit that I don't really know what is causing this, as I'm rather new to Android. I suspect that the GC does delete all my variables after a while when the Settings class haven't been used - causing all settings to be wiped when the user returns a few hours later. This however does not explain why the buttons doesn't work (one of them require no setting).

This main activity can start other activities, and these can again launch new activities.

I think all my problems can be solved if I can just force the whole app to close when HOME is pressed, and thereby force it to be started from scratch whenever the icon is pressed - forcing the listeners on the buttons and the settings to be loaded.

I read on here about "android:clearTaskOnLaunch", " android:launchMode" and "android:finishOnTaskLaunch" but I'm not quite sure how to use these correct.

Anyone who could either explain to me why the buttons does not work, or what might happen to the variables in my Settings class when the app has been in the background for a while, or maybe give me a few good hints on how to use the "activity" settigns properly.

**EDIT**: The app will be running Android 1.6+, so I can't use any newer functions or anything...

Thank you very much

Comment: Depending on what kind of data structures you want your settings to be, you'll probably be better served using the SharedPreferences class. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) The seemingly uncaught button is a bit of a mystery. Mind posting the code that creates it/sets the listener?

Comment: When I load the settings during the Splashscreen I load settings from sharedPreferences, so I already use these as much as I can. However I also get some data from a webserver, which is parsed into objects and references are kept directly in Settings class or to lists containing them in Settings class. I could solve some of the problem by using sharedPreferences as much as I can, but the objects parsed from the webservice will still get wiped it seems. 
One more comment in a second...

Comment: Regarding the buttons and listeners - I will edit the code in the OP, but as I just tried it on my way back from work, starting app and pressing home, and the opening when I got back home. The typeface is set to the standard, and I get an error from one button indicating that the username (read from sharedPrefs and while running a ref is saved in Settings class) has been set to null (wiped). 
The listeners do work (my bad) - I will edit OP to explain what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- DO NOT override home key functionality. Maybe you'll find something, somewhere, that would allow you to do this. A god-fearing, standards-embracing application would not in any way override the home key.
- Just put android:clearTaskOnLaunch=true in your manifest. This will ensure that your main activity will be launched everytime you press the launcher icon.

> I suspect that the GC does delete all my variables after a while when
>   the Settings class haven't been used - causing all settings to be
>   wiped when the user returns a few hours later

- Android is not that evil to do this to your app. It may kill your application, services, and whatever is running on the background after some time of inactivity and/or need for more memory, but will never leave your application hanging in there without your variables.

Comment: I't not attempting to override the HOME button in any way (I read that this should never be done), I'm just looking for a way to start the application from the launcher (loading settings) whenever the app icon is pressed. 

I'm not sure what is happing to the references in my Settings class (contains only static variables and methods), but after a while on the homescreen on then opening app again, they seem to be gone - how this is happening I have no idea. But it only happens when its hidden for a while (tried on the way back from work, 30 mins and it happened). If only 1 min - all works fine

Comment: Take a look at the edits I just made - not sure if it's just in my head, but I think all the errors I see can be caused by missing variables as set in Settings class

Answer (score 0):

I had  actually customized this for android 2.0 development 2.0.May be better  options are available now.What I did was to declare all activities global and when you click home button from anywhere we check whether each of them is not  null.If not null close them and set references to null.The activities are only declared globally.They are defined only when they are to be used.

Comment: The app must run on Android 1.6+, so using 2.0 stuff is not an option. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 4.0 or higher, you can enable "Don't keep activities" in Developer options?.  If you don't have a 4.0 device, then use the emulator.

Comment: The app have to run on Android 1.6+, so using functions implemented in newer versions is not an option. Thanks tho.

I have added this to OP

Comment: I think that it is very likely that what causes the app to crash when in the background for a while is the same in 4.0 or 1.6, so fixing it in 4.0 will probably fix it in 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

you have to kill all the activities that are on the top of current activity on Home button and 
for do that you have to override Home key functionality in which you have to write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,login.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this will clear all the activities on the top of that activity where you press home key and switch it to login activity and

if you don't want to override Home key functionallity then you have to write only one in **Androidmanifest.xml** that is **android:clearTaskOnLaunch=true** from this when ever you click on app icon it will starts your 1st activity

I Suggest the second approach is best suted for you.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, in my app I just added **finish();** in the  **onStop()** method after everything i do there and it worked as a charm.